# Function to add a second vertical axis to the right of the graphic

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with a function that adds a second vertical axis to the right of a graphic done with ggplot, applying a scale factor to the variable that is represented.

The code of both my graphic and my function is below:

```
#Libraries
library(ggplot2)    

#Data   
df <- data.frame(
      equis = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
      ygrega = c(80,75,85,80,81,70,82,73,83,72,82,75),
      zeta = c(30,30,30,30,20,20,30,30,20,20,30,30),
      tip= c("inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det")
    )

#Graphic
grafTest <- ggplot(data= df, aes(x= equis)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= ygrega, col= tip), alpha= 0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(y= ygrega, col= tip), size= 0.6, alpha= 0.6)

#Function
afeSecAxi <- function(graf, var, facMul, namAxi, type){

  if(type=="line"){
    graf <- graf + geom_line(aes(y=var*facMul)) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ . /facMul, name = paste(namAxi)))

    return(graf)

  }else if(type=="point"){
    graf <- graf + geom_point(aes(y=var*facMul, colour= paste(namAxi))) +
      scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ . /facMul, name = paste(namAxi)))

    return(graf)

  }else{

    stop("Not valid type of graphic ")

  }

}

#Function example
afeSecAxi(graf = grafTest, var = df$zeta, facMul = 2.5, namAxi = "zeta", type = "line")
```

When I run the code, I obtain the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'facMul' not found
```

I don't know why is appearing this error, because if I run the same code out of the function, the graphic is done correctly, as I show bellow:

```
#Libraries
library(ggplot2)    

#Data 
df <- data.frame(
      equis = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6),
      ygrega = c(80,75,85,80,81,70,82,73,83,72,82,75),
      zeta = c(30,30,30,30,20,20,30,30,20,20,30,30),
      tip= c("inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det","inrix","det")
    )

#Graphic
grafTest <- ggplot(data= df, aes(x= equis)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= ygrega, col= tip), alpha= 0.6) +
  geom_point(aes(y= ygrega, col= tip), size= 0.6, alpha= 0.6)

  graf = grafTest
  var = df$zeta
  facMul = 2.5
  namAxi = "zeta"
  type = "line"


graf <- graf + geom_line(aes(y=var*facMul)) +
              scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ . /facMul, name = paste(namAxi)))

plot(graf)
```

Anyone knows why is appearing the error?

Bellow is shown the initial graphic and the graphic with the second axis:

[image: Initial graphic]

[image: Second axis graphic]

Regards and thanks in adavance.

Comment: I don't get an error when running the example that you gave (running **ggplot2** version 3.0.0). Have you tried running the code in a clean environment?

Comment: Why aren't you just using `sec_axis`?

Comment: @MikkoMarttila thank you, the problem was the version of my ggplot2 package wasn't the 3.0.0. With this version it works.